# How to implement a C# model class for properties that may occur multiple times (prop, prop2, prop3, ...)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, model

I have a ASP.NET Core 2.1 API web service.

The web service should be extended with an new API endpoint that can consume the following request (HTTP POST body is www-form-urlencoded):

```
foo=1&bar=2&baz=3&baz_2=3&baz_2=4
```

The above www-form-urlencoded in a more human readable way:

- Parameter `foo` with value `1`.
- Parameter `bar` with value `2`.
- Parameter `baz` with value `3`.
- Parameter `baz_2` with value `4`.

The parameters `foo` and `bar` exists exactly and only 1 time within the request. The parameter `baz` exists at least 1 time within the request. It is common that the `baz` parameter occurs multiple times, but I have seen occasions in which there where only a single `baz` parameter.

I have no impact on the sender. I have the option to either consume the request in the above described format, or cannot receive the data at all. And I need this data, which will be supplied only in the above described manner.

I have modeled a C# model class for the parameters that exists only 1 time within the request:

```
namespace StackOverflow.WebAPI.Models
{
    public class ConsumeRequest
    {
        public int foo { get; set; }
        public int bar { get; set; }

        public ConsumeRequest()
        {
            foo = 0;
            bar = 0;
        }

        public ConsumeRequest(int foo, int bar)
        {
            this.foo = foo;
            this.bar = bar;
        }
    }
}
```

The model shall be used as a `Action` parameter, such as:

```
namespace StackOverflow.WebAPI
{
    public class EndpointController : BaseController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Consume([FromBody] ConsumeRequest data)
        {
            // Do something with data.
            return new JsonResult("ok");
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally, `baz` would be a `List<int>`. The order of the `List` would represent the "order" of the `baz`s (`baz`, `baz_2`, `baz_3`, ...).

**How do I extend the model implementation to feature the `baz` parameter?**

Comment: What have you tried? It seems like a homework assignment.

Comment: What could I have tried? The documentation states, that when the parameter occurs multiple times (the exact same parameter name without prefix/suffix), then there is the possibility to implement it as an array. I found no info about this prefix/suffix stuff. And it is not practical to implement hundreds of `baz_N` properties. Possibly missing instances because I only have implemented until `N` but there where a `baz_(N+1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a valid request format to bind as you're looking to. The `baz_2` key will literally translate to something like a `Baz_2` property, not the second item in `Baz` collection. For that, the key must be something like `baz[]`, repeated as many times as necessary. For example:

```
?baz[]=3&baz[]=4
```

Which will create a collection of the values `[3, 4]`.

If the issue is that you don't have control over the format of the query string, that's a *client* issue, not an issue for you. An API is literally an *interface*. It enforces a particular form and function of the request, and not conforming to that interface is a *bad request*. You should not ever alter you API to accommodate a client; rather the client needs to alter their code to conform to your API.

That said, if you have no choice here, the only thing you can do is literally add a `Baz_2` property and `Baz_3`, `Baz_4`, etc. up to as many as you need. However, there will always be some limit, due to these having to be literal properties that you must actually add to the class that you're binding to.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I thought so as well, but hoped there is a way. I guess I have to manually parse the data. But I bet that this will bite me some day

Comment: I would suggest designing the API as it should be designed, and then add an endpoint specifically for this that translates the request into a proper format. You could even forgo the actual binding process and directly work with the query string to give yourself more flexibility. Then, clients that behave appropriately can hit the good endpoint and you only need to maintain the translation layer.